# Find Win7 Network "Other Devices" in C#

Tags: c#, networking, windows-7-x64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IP Camera, how to detect it on the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165536/ip-camera-how-to-detect-it-on-the-network)

I have an IP Camera connected to my network which shows up as an Other Device from the Win7 Explorer Network.

I'm trying to find the camera, and its IP from C#.

I've tried several WMI queries with no luck. I'm able to list all the PC's connected to the LAN, but not any Other Devices.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You could try having a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15537/Camera-Vision-video-surveillance-on-C

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165536/ip-camera-how-to-detect-it-on-the-network